# ios local notification didreceivelocalnotification

Tags: ios, scheduled-tasks, uilocalnotification

Will the "didreceivelocalnotification" method be called if the user has disabled notifications for my app? I need a way to call a method on a specific date . Even if the user doesn't want to see a notification the method should be called. Is there a better way than local notifications for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not called.

Its better you to save your task into a server, and run it over there.
You cant guarantee that your user dont delete you app or enable its notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the `didReceiveLocalNotification:` method would be called only if your app is running and local notification fires while the app is running.

It seems that once you "send" the local notification to the system using `scheduleLocalNotification:` or `presentLocalNotificationNow:` method, it is to be fired.

So when the "fire date" comes, if your app is running, the `didReceiveLocalNotification:` method would be called.

I ran a sample application and confirmed that.